# What is the way to use security trimming in masterpage deployed via VS in 2013?

Tags: 2013, master-page, security-trimming

[This article mentions](http://blogs.technet.com/b/vinitt/archive/2013/04/27/hide-ribbon-for-anonymous-users-sharepoint-2013.aspx) how we can modify the masterpage html file in SP2013.

However, we are deploying a '.master' file and setting the masterpage via VS package. What is the way that we can perform security trimming on a master page to hide ribbon based on user permission? (we can open the VS project and make changes to this '.master' file)

I have found [article that does this on SP2010,](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zwsong/archive/2010/04/29/how-to-hide-ribbon-from-users-without-edit-page-privilege.aspx) however is it good practice to use it on SP2013? How can we hide the ribbon from users with 'read only' permission?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have to show/hide parts of the Ribbon based on permissions then `SPSecurityTrimmedControl` is the ideal way to do it even if you are on SP 2013. You can use `ViewListItems` permissions to hide the Ribbon from users with `Read Only` permissions. See this http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/ms412690 for all possible types of Permissions which can be used.

Comment: This control is present also in 2010 :)

Comment: Yes and OP wants to know if it still good practice to use it on 2013.

Comment: If I use 'ViewListItems', then the ribbon will only be visible to users with 'ViewListItems' permission. (am I correct?) I want that the user with read only permission should not be able to see the ribbon.

Comment: Yes you are correct. Do you mean anonymous users by readonly users?

Comment: Example: 'User A' has permission to only 'read' list items. Then, for that user, the ribbon should be hidden.